# Spring boot reactive and mongodb 'command insert requires authentication'

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb

I created a project using Spring Boot 2.3.1 with webflux and MongoDB in a docker container. The project starts normally and connect in MongoDB with the params declared in *application.properties*.

The problem beggins when I try execute a CRUD operation "insert". The following log is generated:

```
500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/configuracao"

org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'command insert requires authentication' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "command insert requires authentication", "code": 13, "codeName": "Unauthorized"}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'command insert requires authentication' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "command insert requires authentication", "code": 13, "codeName": "Unauthorized"}
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:133) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoError] :
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:247)
    com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.AbstractSubscription.onError(AbstractSubscription.java:139)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onError ⇢ at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.AbstractSubscription.onError(AbstractSubscription.java:139)
    |_                          Flux.onErrorMap ⇢ at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate.createFlux(ReactiveMongoTemplate.java:651)
    |_                                Flux.last ⇢ at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate.insertDocument(ReactiveMongoTemplate.java:1578)
    |_                                 Mono.map ⇢ at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate.insertDocument(ReactiveMongoTemplate.java:1578)
    |_                             Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate.lambda$doInsert$35(ReactiveMongoTemplate.java:1344)
    |_                             Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate.doInsert(ReactiveMongoTemplate.java:1342)
    |_                                 Mono.map ⇢ at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.encode(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:120)
    |_                                Mono.flux ⇢ at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.encode(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:121)
    |_                       Flux.singleOrEmpty ⇢ at org.springframework.http.codec.EncoderHttpMessageWriter.write(EncoderHttpMessageWriter.java:121)
    |_                       Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ at org.springframework.http.codec.EncoderHttpMessageWriter.write(EncoderHttpMessageWriter.java:122)
    |_                             Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.http.codec.EncoderHttpMessageWriter.write(EncoderHttpMessageWriter.java:126)
    |_                               checkpoint ⇢ Handler br.com.example.exampleapplication.controller.ConfiguracaoController#save(Configuracao) [DispatcherHandler]
    |_                             Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.lambda$handleResult$5(DispatcherHandler.java:172)
    |_                       Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handleResult(DispatcherHandler.java:171)
    |_                             Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handle(DispatcherHandler.java:147)
    |_                               Mono.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_                         Mono.doOnSuccess ⇢ at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter.filter(MetricsWebFilter.java:78)
    |_                           Mono.doOnError ⇢ at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter.filter(MetricsWebFilter.java:79)
    |_                   Mono.transformDeferred ⇢ at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter.filter(MetricsWebFilter.java:73)
    |_                               checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_                               Mono.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:119)
    |_                               Mono.error ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler$CheckpointInsertingHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:98)
    |_                               checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/configuracao" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
    |_                       Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:77)
```

Reading the [Spring Data MongoDB Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-connectors), I create a custom Bean for mongodb config as suggested:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create("mongodb://exampleapp:example@localhost:27017/exampledb");
    }

//    @Bean
//    public ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory() {
//        return new SimpleReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory(MongoClients.create("mongodb://exampleapp:example@localhost:27017/exampledb"), database);
//    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return database;
    }
```

I tried with *MongoClient* and with *ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory* and I can't execute the *save* method. Always is returned that *'command insert requires authentication'*.

For the docker container I'm using this script to initialize the database after container startup:

```
db.auth('mongoadmin', 'mongoadmin')
db = db.getSiblingDB('exampledb')
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "exampleapp",
        pwd: "example",
        roles: [
            {
                role: "readWrite",
                db: "exampledb"
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

The application connects successfully on the startup, I can connect on the database using mongo-express or another gui tool.

What I doing wrong here? How I can configure this spring boot reactive app to propperly integrate with mongodb?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be having a property like this in your properties/yaml file

spring.data.mongodb.uri=spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/test

Also are you able to do read operation? 
MongoDB auto configure will setup the client for you.

Comment: @DhruvG Thank you by your repply and sorry for the long time to response. I remove the mongoClient method and lefted to spring instantiate the client, I added the uri property in my application.properties like your example. After this the error changed. Now is :

Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256, userName='exampleapp', source='exampledb', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>};

I made other change, added on docker-compose "command: "--bind_ip_all" " to allow other requests origins .

Answer (score 4):

In case you are still having this issue. I had a similar problem and resolved it by using reactiveMongoClient() instead of mongoClient().

Replace:

```
 @Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    return MongoClients.create("mongodb://exampleapp:example@localhost:27017/exampledb");
}
```

With:

```
@Override
public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {
    return MongoClients.create("mongodb://exampleapp:example@localhost:27017/exampledb");
}
```

Your bean should look like:

```
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
@Slf4j
public class MongoDBCConfig extends 
AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return "dbname";
}

@Override
public MongoClient reactiveMongoClient() {
    return MongoClients.create("mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/authSource=auth-source");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you by your reply. As sugested by @DhruvG, I removed the client instantiation and left to spring auto configure it. Without mongodb auth enabled works well, however, if the mongodb authentication is enabled the spring boot connects at startup but fail when it try to execute the insert. How do you configured using reactiveMongoClient()?

Comment: Dude, you are awesome! Literally struggeled 1 week to make this work, and after several failed attemps now it finaly works.

Comment: ++ you're a saviour for those learning the reactive mongo :)